# Simple two variable am-gm inequality

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Given $x,y \in \Bbb{R}$, show that:$$x^2+y^2+1\ge xy+y+x $$
I tried using the fact that $x^2+y^2 \ge 2xy$ But then I'm not sure how to go on, Also tried factoring but didn't help much, also tried substituting $\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}$ instead of $xy$ but that gave me the same result of the first substitution, i.e. $xy+1\ge x+y$

This inequality seems very easy, I'm feeling dumb for not having solved it yet

Comment: Fix $y$, differentiate w.r.t. $x$, etc

Comment: @MartinR I just didn't see them being equivalent, I well new that one inequality

Comment: @Spasoje Durovic Substitute $c=1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $$a^2-2ab+b^2 = (a-b)^2\geq 0\implies a^2+b^2\geq 2ab$$ we have $$ x^2+y^2\geq 2xy$$
$$x^2+1\geq 2x$$
$$y^2+1\geq 2y$$
Now add all these...

Answer (score 6):

Hint: Use that $$x^2+y^2+z^2\geq xy+yz+zx$$ holds for all real numbers $$x,y,z$$
this is $$(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2\geq 0$$

Answer (score 2):

We need to prove that
$$y^2-(x+1)y+x^2-x+1\geq0,$$ for which it's enough to prove that
$$(x+1)^2-4(x^2-x+1)\leq0$$ or $$(x-1)^2\geq0.$$